# Smallest rubber wheel that can be turned by a technic axle

Tags: technic, piece-information, wheel

What the smallest rubber wheels that can be turned by a Technic axle?

This is what I have so far

[image]

[Wheel Full Rubber Balloon with Axle hole #4288](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4288#T=S&C=11&O)

Background: I'm building a GBC and I want to push the balls at speed across an open area. I plan to hide small spinning wheels in the opening they go through and assume that rubber tyres are the best solution.

Comment: There are some small tires that fit on half-bushings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the smallest one in diameter is the tire [3641](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3641&idColor=11#T=P&C=11)

[image]

with the bush [4265c](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4265c&idColor=9#T=P&C=9).

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the tire [3139](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3139&idColor=11#T=P&C=11)

[image]

which has a smooth surface and also compatible (but a little bit loosely) with the same bush.

Answer (score 3):

While it is technically not a rubber wheel, you can use an axle with a half-bush and with an additional rubber band to provide grip. Tensioning the band between two such axles will form a short conveyor belt with a rubbery surface, which could be used for transporting balls when surrounded by appropriate elements to form a channel:

[image: quick-and-dirty MS Paint sketch]

(the black lines are axles, the grey ovals are half-bushes, the red freehand-circle is a rubber band and the round spotty ugliness is supposed to be my rendition of a LEGO football)